# Could not download windows server core docker image

Tags: windows, docker

I have tried from both CMD/PowerShell and Kitematic same error: **"read tcp 192.168.0.101:50143->204.79.197.219:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"**
Is it my ISP problem or anything else can't figure it out.

**Docker details:
Client:**
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:05:28 2018
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

**Server:**
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.0-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       0ffa825
  Built:            Wed Jul 18 19:23:19 2018
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false

Comment: I have been facing the same issue for some time now. I had it working on my machine. Recently, I removed the image from machine by mistake.  I am now trying to pull from repo it give the same error. If you open http://204.79.197.219/  the link in browser it indicates that the network is down. I think it needs to be reported to microsoft.

Comment: Same issue is still happening